# Protobuf net not serializing when using WCF

Tags: wcf, protobuf-net

I am trying to use protobuf to serialize my WCF calls, but it seems the object is not getting serialized by the client.  Some things to note:

- I am using a shared DTO library.
- I am using a ChannelFactory to
  invoke the service (so the types are not losing their datamember
  attributes).
- I can serialize and deserialize the objects just using
  normal protobuf.net code, so the types themselves seem to be ok
- I am using version 2.0.0.480 of protobuf.net
- I haven't posted the service code as the problem is with the outgoing message (message log posted below)
- The client and service work fine if I don't use the protobuf endpoint behaviour.

My main method looks as follows

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Base.PrepareMetaDataForSerialization();
        FactoryHelper.InitialiseFactoryHelper(new ServiceModule());
        Member m = new Member();
        m.FirstName = "Mike";
        m.LastName = "Hanrahan";
        m.UserId = Guid.NewGuid();
        m.AccountStatus = MemberAccountStatus.Blocked;
        m.EnteredBy = "qwertt";
        ChannelFactory<IMembershipService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IMembershipService>("NetTcpBinding_MembershipService");
        var client = factory.CreateChannel();

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize<Member>(ms, m);
            Console.WriteLine(ms.Length.ToString());
            ms.Position = 0;
            var member2 = Serializer.Deserialize<Member>(ms);
            Console.WriteLine(member2.EnteredBy);
            Console.WriteLine(member2.FirstName);
        }

        var result = client.IsMemberAllowedToPurchase(m);

        System.Console.Write(result.IsValid.ToString());
        factory.Close();
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

My client configuration looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="NetTcpBinding_Common" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
      hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
      maxBufferSize="1000065536" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
        enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Proto.Common.EndpointBehavior">
      <protobuf />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="protobuf" type="ProtoBuf.ServiceModel.ProtoBehaviorExtension, protobuf-net, Version=2.0.0.480, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=257b51d87d2e4d67" />
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
<client>
  <endpoint address="net.tcp://mikes-pc:12002/MembershipService.svc"
    behaviorConfiguration="Proto.Common.EndpointBehavior" binding="netTcpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_Common" contract="PricesForMe.Core.Entities.ServiceInterfaces.IMembershipService"
    name="NetTcpBinding_MembershipService">
    <identity>
      <userPrincipalName value="Mikes-PC\Mike" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging
       logEntireMessage="true"
       logMalformedMessages="true"
       logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
       logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
       maxMessagesToLog="3000"
       maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000"/>
</diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
</startup>
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel"
          switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
          propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="traceListener"
          type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
          initializeData="E:\Work\Logs\IMembershipServiceWcfTrace_Client.svclog"  />
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
    <listeners>
      <add name="messages"
      type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
      initializeData="E:\Work\Logs\IMembershipServiceWcfTrace_Client_messages.svclog" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
</system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

After logging the client message, I get the following entry in the log

```
    <MessageLogTraceRecord>
    <s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.pricesforme.com/services/MembershipService/IsMemberAllowedToPurchase</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:8b545576-c453-4be6-8d5c-9913e2cca4bf</a:MessageID>
    <ActivityId CorrelationId="b4e9361f-1fbc-4b2d-b7ee-fb493847998a" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">6d712899-62fd-4547-9517-e9de452305c6</ActivityId>
    <a:ReplyTo>
    <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink"></VsDebuggerCausalityData>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
    <IsMemberAllowedToPurchase xmlns="http://www.pricesforme.com/services/">
    <proto></proto>
    </IsMemberAllowedToPurchase>
    </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
    </MessageLogTraceRecord>
```

So as can been seen in the above log message the proto entry has no data in it.  My member class looks as follows:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using PricesForMe.Core.Entities.Common;
    using PricesForMe.Core.Entities.Ordering;

    namespace PricesForMe.Core.Entities.Members
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This entity represents a member or user of the site.
        /// </summary>
        [DataContract]
        [Serializable]
        public class Member: User
        {
            public Member()
                :base()
            {
                EntityType = Entities.EntityType.Member;
            }

            [DataMember(Order = 20)]
            public int Id { get; set; }

            [DataMember(Order = 21)]
            public string MemberName { get; set; }

            [DataMember(Order = 22)]
            public PaymentInfo DefaultPaymentMethod { get; set; }

            [DataMember(Order = 23)]
            public MemberAccountStatus AccountStatus { get; set; }

            #region static

            public static readonly string CacheCollectionKey = "MemberCollection";

            private static readonly string CacheItemKeyPrefix = "Member:";

            public static string GetCacheItemKey(int id)
            {
                return CacheItemKeyPrefix + id.ToString();
            }

            #endregion
        }
    }
```

The parent user class looks as follows:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;

    namespace PricesForMe.Core.Entities.Common
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This class represents a user in the system.  For example, a user could be a member or a merchant user.
        /// </summary>
        [DataContract]
        [Serializable]
        public class User: Base
        {
            public User()
                :base()
            {
                EntityType = Entities.EntityType.User;
            }

            [DataMember(Order = 10)]
            public Guid UserId { get; set; }

            [DataMember(Order = 11, Name = "First Name")]
            public string FirstName { get; set; }

            [DataMember(Order = 12, Name = "Last Name")]
            public string LastName { get; set; }

            }
        }
    }
```

And the base class looks as follows:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Reflection;
    using ProtoBuf.Meta;

    namespace PricesForMe.Core.Entities
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This is the base class for all entities involved in the request/response pattern of our services
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// The objects derived from this class are used to transfer data from our service classes to our UIs and back again and they should 
        /// not contain any logic.
        /// </remarks>
        [DataContract]
        [Serializable]
        public abstract class Base
        {
            public Base()
            {
                //Set some defaults for this
                EnteredBy = System.Environment.UserName;
                EnteredSource = System.Environment.MachineName;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// This is the record timestamp
            /// </summary>
            [DataMember(Order = 2)]
            public DateTime RecordTimeStamp { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            /// This is the name of the user who last edited the entity
            /// </summary>
            [DataMember(Order = 3)]
            public string EnteredBy { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            /// This is the source of the last edited entity
            /// </summary>
            [DataMember(Order = 4)]
            public string EnteredSource { get; set; }

            [DataMember(Order = 5)]
            private PricesForMe.Core.Entities.Common.ValidationResult _validationResult = null;
            /// <summary>
            /// Data on the validity of the entity.
            /// </summary>
            public PricesForMe.Core.Entities.Common.ValidationResult ValidationData
            {
                get
                {
                    _validationResult = Validate();
                    return _validationResult;
                }
                set
                {
                    _validationResult = value;
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Flag denoting if the record is a new record or not.
            /// </summary>
            /// <remarks>
            /// To flag an entity as an existing record call the "FlagAsExistingReport()" method.
            /// </remarks>
            public bool IsNewRecord
            {
                get
                {
                    return _isNewRecord;
                }
            }

            [DataMember(Order = 6)]
            protected bool _isNewRecord = true;
            /// <summary>
            /// Flags the entity as a record that already exists in the database
            /// </summary>
            /// <remarks>
            /// This is a method rather than a field to demonstrait that this should be called with caution (as opposed to inadvertantly setting a flag!)
            /// <para>
            /// Note that this method should only need to be called on object creation if the entity has a composite key.  Otherwise the flag is
            /// set when the id is being set.  It should always be called on saving an entity.
            /// </para>
            /// </remarks>
            public void FlagAsExistingRecord()
            {
                _isNewRecord = false;
            }

            public virtual PricesForMe.Core.Entities.Common.ValidationResult Validate()
            {
                if (_validationResult == null)
                {
                    _validationResult = new PricesForMe.Core.Entities.Common.ValidationResult();
                    _validationResult.MemberValidations = new List<Common.ValidationResult>();
                    _validationResult.RulesViolated = new List<Common.ValidationRule>();
                }
                return _validationResult;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// This is the type of entity we are working with
            /// </summary>
            [DataMember(Order = 7)]
            private EntityType _entityType = EntityType.Unknown;
            public EntityType EntityType
            {
                get
                {
                    return _entityType;
                }
                protected set
                {
                    _entityType = value;
                }
            }


            /// <summary>
            /// Flag to say if the id generated for this class need to be int64 in size.
            /// </summary>
            [DataMember(Order = 9)]
            public bool IdRequiresInt64 { get; protected set; }

            /// <summary>
            /// This method tells us if the database id has been assigned.  Note that this does
            /// not mean the entity has been saved, only if the id has been assigned (so the id could be greater than 0, but the
            /// entity could still be a NewRecord
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns></returns>
            [DataMember(Order = 8)]
            public bool HasDbIdBeenAssigned { get; protected set; }

            private Guid _validationId = Guid.NewGuid();
            public Guid EntityValidationId
            {
                get
                {
                    return _validationId;
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Converts an object into another type of object based on the mapper class provided.
            /// </summary>
            /// <remarks>
            /// This method allows us to easily convert between objects without concerning ourselves with the mapping implementation.  This
            /// allows us to use various mapping frameworks (e.g. Automapper, ValueInjector) or create our own custom mapping.
            /// </remarks>
            /// <typeparam name="TDestination">The type we want to convert to</typeparam>
            /// <typeparam name="KMapper">The mapping type</typeparam>
            /// <returns>The new type</returns>
            public TDestination ConvertTo<TDestination, TSource, KMapper>()
                where KMapper : IEntityMapper<TDestination, TSource>
                where TSource : class
            {
                return Base.ConvertToItem<TDestination, TSource, KMapper>(this as TSource);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Returns all known child types
            /// </summary>
            public IEnumerable<Type> GetAllTypes()
            {
                Assembly current = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
                List<Type> derivedTypes = new List<Type>();
                var allTypes = current.GetTypes();
                foreach (var t in allTypes)
                {
                    if (t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Base)))
                    {
                        derivedTypes.Add(t);
                    }
                }
                return derivedTypes;
            }

            #region Static Methods
            /// <summary>
            /// Converts a list of one type to a list of another type
            /// </summary>
            /// <typeparam name="TDestination">The type we want to convert to</typeparam>
            /// <typeparam name="TSource">The source type</typeparam>
            /// <typeparam name="KMapper">The mapper class</typeparam>
            /// <param name="source">The source list of items.</param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public static List<TDestination> ConvertToList<TDestination, TSource, KMapper>(IEnumerable<TSource> source)
                where KMapper : IEntityMapper<TDestination, TSource>
                where TSource : class
            {
                List<TDestination> result = new List<TDestination>();
                KMapper mapper = Activator.CreateInstance<KMapper>();
                foreach (var item in source)
                {
                    result.Add(mapper.Convert(item));
                }
                return result;
            }

            public static TDestination ConvertToItem<TDestination, TSource, KMapper>(TSource source)
                where KMapper : IEntityMapper<TDestination, TSource>
                where TSource : class
            {
                //Return default (i.e. null for ref objects) if the source is null.
                if (source == null) { return default(TDestination); }

                KMapper mapper = Activator.CreateInstance<KMapper>();
                return mapper.Convert(source);
            }


            private static object _metaLock = new object();
            private static bool _metaDataPrepared = false;
            /// <summary>
            /// Creates protobuf type models from the entities in this assembly
            /// </summary>
            public static void PrepareMetaDataForSerialization()
            {
                lock (_metaLock)
                {
                    if (_metaDataPrepared) { return; }

                    Assembly current = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
                    var allTypes = current.GetTypes();
                    foreach (var t in allTypes)
                    {
                        checkType(t);
                    }
                }
            }

            private static void checkType(Type type)
            {
                Assembly current = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
                var allTypes = current.GetTypes();
                int key = 1000;
                foreach (var t in allTypes)
                {
                    if (t.IsSubclassOf(type) && t.BaseType == type)
                    {
                        RuntimeTypeModel.Default[type].AddSubType(key, t);
                        key++;
                    }
                }
            }

            #endregion
        }
    }
```

The `PrepareMetaDataForSerialization` method on base configures the RuntimeModel for protobuf.net, but I mentioned earlier, the serialization and deserialization works fine outside of the WCF, so I think the DTOs are ok.  Any ideas around what could be causing the problem are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

k; the element name looks correct (`proto`, matching `XmlProtoSerializer.PROTO_ELEMENT`), so protobuf-net definitely tried to do something. It also doesn't include `@nil` to represent `null`, so it knows there was data. Beyond that, it serializes the object to a `MemoryStream` and writes it as base-64 (identical to how `byte[]` etc is represented, which allows WCF to hoist the data silently and automatically if things like `MTOM` are enabled). So the question becomes "why would my type serialize to nothing?"

The use of `DataContract`/`DataMember` is fine, and matches my existing WCF integration tests.

I wonder how much of this is due to the inheritance (only one of the members shown relates to the concrete type, and I would hazard a guess that `Blocked` is `0`, which has particular handling).

I cannot, however, emphasise enough how unsafe your current inheritance handling is; the numbers matter, and reflection makes no guarantees re order. I would strongly suggest you revisit this and make inheritance numbering more predicatable.

Very minor observation, but there is no need to store `EntityType` - it is entirey redundant and could be handled via polymorphism with no need for storage.

Also, there's an important bug that `_metaDataPrepared` is never set to true.

However! Ultimately I cannot reproduce this; I have used your code (or most of it) to generate [an integration test](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/Examples/Issues/SO10115538.cs), and - it passes; meaning: using WCF, `NetTcpBinding`, your classes (including your inheritance fixup code), and the protobuf packing, it *just works*. The data that goes over the wire is the data we expect.

Happy to try to help further, but I need to be able to repro it... and right now, I can't.

The first thing I'd do is add the missing `_metaDataPrepared = true;` to see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  I went back to first principles and created a very simple class with no inheritence and just a single member and was still getting the problem.  However after many hours of effort this morning, it turns out the answer was something simple.  I am hosting the service in IIS, and IIS was not picking up the endpoint behaviour configuration (due to the reasons outlined in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243914/wcf-service-hosted-in-iis-7-binding-configuration-settings-are-ignored).  As soon as I fixed that everything worked fine.

Comment: Also, the reason that the message logging was showing the empty proto value is that I was not reading the logs correctly.  There were two entries in the log for each request.  One with a source of "ServiceLevelSendRequest" which had the empty proto node, but then there was a second one with a source of "TransportSend" which had the encoded stream.

Comment: Finally, thanks for spotting that _metaDataPrepared bug (this was just a quick method while testing...that actual method will be private and get called once in the static constructor for the base class).  The EntityType was being stored as the original DataContractor deserialization doesn't call the constructor (there is another method that can be implmented which it does call, but it was easier for me to just store it).  

Regarding the inheritence numbering...have you any further advice on that? (I have a test in my unit tests to ensure the numbering is unique..is that enough?).  Thanks.

Comment: @Mike in addition to unique, it needs to be the same between client and server. Reflection usually doesn't guarantee any particular order, and if your client/server are versioned separately it needs to be able to survive having an extra type on one side only.

Answer (score 0):

I thought you need to use ProtoContract instead of DataContract per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130871/protobuf-net-wcf-response-is-empty) SO? Also, make sure you set "Reuse types in referenced assemblies" when configuring service reference. And according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775082/datacontract-serialization-with-protobuf-net-r275) SO they support data contracts but you have to have the order set  [DataMember(Order = 0)] (at least that's what worked for me).

Comment: TH OP states they are using assembly sharing, so the "Reuse types" in unnecessary. There are also explicit `Order`s set.

Comment: Thanks I stand corrected. Where do you set _metaDataPrepared = true?

Comment: I linked to a full example including that in my answer